# install_failed_update_incompatible package "package name" singnature do not match with previously installed version

Tags: android, apk, signed-apk

[image]Getting this error while making update version of apk .There are so many thread related to this but my issue is different.
On play store my app version name is **1.0** and right now i am making **1.1** and i have also update version code.
And I am using same keystore file.
I am getting this issue only if I install on above play store apk.
If I am installing on above **1.0** apk which was **saved in my local machine** then it is updating perfectly  and this apk  I had updated on play store.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Signed apk for both ?local and new 1.1 .

Comment: yes i have tried by saving conditional in build.gradle  and also by build>create signed apk.
in both cases it is compatible with local build but on with play store build.